# Length of geometric line with exclusive endpoints

Tags: geometry

Say on a simple coordinate plane there is a function f(x) such that the domain includes only a line segment "A" extending from the origin, (0,0), to... say (4,0), x=0 and x=4 inclusive in this domain.

The line segment "A"'s length is 4 units.

But if we exclude 4 and 0 from the domain, is the line segment now <4 units long?

Comment: The length stays the same (since the endpoints removed have zero length).

Comment: Why would excluding points make the segment longer, Jdog?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant <4 units. That's embarrasing.

Comment: FYI: There's an entire field of mathematics that deals with stuff like this: ["Measure Theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics). Interestingly, with an appropriate definition, you can remove certain *infinite* sets of points from a segment ---not merely the two endpoints--- yet leave its "size" in tact.

Answer (score 1):

Since the open interval $(0,4)$ is a subset of the closed interval $[0,4]$, the open interval $(0,4)$ certainly can't have length *greater* than $4$.

But for any positive $\epsilon < 4$, the open interval $(0,4)$ contains the subinterval 
$$\left[{\small{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}},4-{\small{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\right]$$
which has length $4-\epsilon$.

Hence, assuming we declare that the interval $(0,4)$ *has* a length, $L$ say, we must have $L \ge 4-\epsilon$.

Thus, $L$ is a real number such that
$$ 4-\epsilon \le L \le 4$$
for all positive values of $\epsilon < 4$, no matter how small.

It follows that $L=4$.